# Docusaurus Localization (l10n)

Tags: localization, docusaurus

I'm using Docusaurus v2 and I'm trying to segregrate a documentation by country, as some features are only available at some specific locations.

I've tried to take avail of the i18n feature, but the problem is that the same sidebar is rendered for all language versions and I'm not able to exclude some features that I don't want to be displayed on a specific language/country.

What can I do to create a documentation that hides/display features on the sidebar based on the selected language/country?